# Как использовать Bootstrap Glyphicons?

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4

В общем, все делаю, как написано [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_glyphs.asp):

```
<p>Envelope icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></p>
```

Т.е вешаю класс, но ничего не происходит.

Стили подключены:

```
 "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
```

Comment: из-за проблем с лицензиями в bootstrap4 glyphicons не включены.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/extend/icons/
>
> Bootstrap doesn’t include an icon library by default, but we have a handful of recommendations for you to choose from. While most icon sets include multiple file formats, we prefer SVG implementations for their improved accessibility and vector support.
>
> Bootstrap по умолчанию не включает библиотеку значков, но у нас есть несколько рекомендаций, из которых вы можете выбрать. Хотя большинство наборов иконок включают несколько форматов файлов, мы предпочитаем реализации SVG для их улучшенной доступности и векторной поддержки.

Comment: а альтернатив не подкинешь?

Comment: https://fontawesome.com